# Masking NetCDF data onto US counties

Tags: coordinate-system, netcdf, masking

I'm a complete beginner in using geographical data. I'm using public [NASA satellite data](https://disc.gsfc.nasa.gov/datasets/M2TMNXAER_5.12.4/summary?keywords=merra-2). What I now want to do is to mask this data onto all US counties, i.e. I want to for example show the PM2.5 concentration in Orange county etc.
There's already a NASA US county mask file on this [website](https://goldsmr4.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/data/MERRA2_CLIM/M2_TMAX_PM25.1/1980/), but it only includes the geographical coordinates for contiguous USA, hence Alaska or Hawai'i is missing.

Can you tell me, how I can maybe add these missing counties to this mask file or even create a new mask file on my own, if that's possible?

Comment: Welcome to GIS Stack Exchange. Please provide more info. If you read this, it will provide guidance on how to edit your question to help us help you: https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3349/asking-good-questions-for-gis-stack-exchange